# How to convert pixels into indices

Tags: c++, allegro, allegro5

The problem it's I need to change a matrix and I just have acess to these positions in pixels `x` and `y`, how can I convert `x` and `y` into an indice ?

E.g :

`char *map[20][17] = {
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    "WFFFFFFFFFFFFFFW",
    "WFWWWWWFFWWWWWFW",
    "WFFFFFFFFFFFFFFW",
    "WFWWWWWFFWWWWWFW",
    "WFFFFFFFFFFFFFFW",
    "WFWWWWWWWWWWWWFW",
    "WFFFFFFWWFFFFFFW",
    "WFFFWFFWWFFWFFFW",
    "WFWWWFFFFFFWWWFW",
    "WFWFFFWWWWFFFWFW",
    "WFFFWFFFFFFWFFFW",
    "WFWWWFWFFWFWWWFW",
    "WFFFWFWWWWFWFFFW",
    "WFFFFFFFFFFFFFFW",
    "WFFFWWWWWWWWFFFW",
    "WFWFFFFFFFFFFWFW",
    "WFWWWWWFFWWWWWFW",
    "WFFFFFFFFFFFFFFW",
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW"};`

`int x_pac = 240, y_pac = 360;`

Using `x_pac` and `y_pac` to access some position on `map`, in this case each one of characters have height = 30 and width = 30.

Comment: Could you, please, provide a [mcve]?

Comment: If each character in the map corresponds to 30 pixels, just divide by 30 to get the index?

Comment: I don't know cause the values of  x and y are altered depending of the user input, it can be decreased or increased. But okay, sorry.

Comment: Very unclear. The map is roughly a 20x16 matrix. What is the relation between this matrix and x_pac and y_pac? And what is heigh and width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can visualize your input.

So you have a map containing a collection of bitmap "image" characters.
Where the size of each bitmap "image" characters can be varied (eg. 30x30).

Say for this example: you have 4x4 char map and each character has a dimension of 6x6.

[image]

If you want to access a specific pixel in a specific character, use this formula:

```
// matrix dimension
matrix_row = <row>
matrix_col = <col>

// bitmap dimension
char_row = <char_row>
char_col = <char_col>
num_pixels = char_row * char_col

// get specific "character" in grid
character_index = ((matrix_row - 1)  * matrix_col) * num_pixels

// get specific "pixel" in character
pixel = character_index * ((char_row - 1) * char_col + pixel_offset)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the indices simply dividing x-y positions by width and height. `row = y_pac / height`. `col = x_pac / width`